# I want to retrieve SFMC Journey Entry source details and Details of Fields used in Decision Split using API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, journeybuilder, soap-api

I have used the following code to fetch Salesforce entry event Details and Fields used in Decision split. But its not working

```
HTTP/1.1 200
```

```json
{
     "Page": 1,
     "PageSize": 50,
     "Count": 5,
     "Items": [
        {
            //This log shows the creation date and time for the journey. The log also includes sourceInteraction if a user created the journey as a copy of an existing journey.
            "action": "Create",
            "key": "some-journey-key",
            "versionNumber": 2,
            "id": "####-####-####-####-####",
            "originalDefinitionId": "####-####-####-####-####",
            "name": "Complete journey",
            "description": "This journey contains a trigger, goal and activities",
            "timeStamp": "2015-10-30T11:49:55.99",
            "user": {
                "name": "Test User 1",
                "UserId": 1234
                },
            "executionMode": "Production",
            "sourceInteraction": {
                "id":"####-####-####-####-####",
                "version": 3,
                "key": "My journey"
                }
        },
        {
            //This log shows a record for each modification of the journey.
            "action": "Modify",
            "key": "some-journey-key",
            "versionNumber": 2,
            "id": "####-####-####-####-####",
            "originalDefinitionId": "####-####-####-####-####",
            "name": "Complete journey",
            "description": "This journey contains a trigger, goal and activities",
            "timeStamp": "2015-10-30T11:49:55.99",
            "user": {
                "name": "Test User 1",
                "UserId": 1234
                },
            "executionMode": "Production"
        },
        {
            //This log shows the publish status for the journey, in this case an error.
            "action": "Publish",
            "key": "some-journey-key",
            "versionNumber": 2,
            "id": "####-####-####-####-####",
            "originalDefinitionId": "####-####-####-####-####",
            "name": "Complete journey",
            "description": "This journey contains a trigger, goal and activities",
            "timeStamp": "2015-10-30T11:49:55.99",
            "user": {
                "name": "Test User 2",
                "userId": 5678
                },
            "executionMode": "Production",
            "publishStatus": "Error",
            "PublishRequestId": "####-####-####-####-####",
            "errors": [
                {
                    "ErrorDetail": "An activity must be created and configured before activation can be successful",
                    "ErrorCode": "VALIDATE_GENERAL_EXCEPTION"
                },
                {
                    "ErrorDetail": "An entry event must be configured before activation can be successful",
                    "ErrorCode": "VALIDATE_GENERAL_EXCEPTION"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            //This log shows the publish status for the journey (in this case, a success).
            "action": "Publish",
            "key": "some-journey-key",
            "versionNumber": 2,
            "id": "####-####-####-####-####",
            "originalDefinitionId": "####-####-####-####-####",
            "name": "Complete journey",
            "description": "This journey contains a trigger, goal and activities",
            "timeStamp": "2015-10-30T11:49:55.99",
            "user": {
                "name": "Test User 2",
                "userId": 5678
                },
            "executionMode": "Production",
            "publishStatus": "PublishCompleted",
            "publishRequestId": "####-####-####-####-####"
        },
        {
            //This log shows the journey ejected 20 contacts when stopped.
            "action": "Stop",
            "key": "some-journey-key",
            "versionNumber": 2,
            "id": "####-####-####-####-####",
            "originalDefinitionId": "####-####-####-####-####",
            "name": "Complete journey",
            "description": "This journey contains a trigger, goal and activities",
            "timeStamp": "2015-10-30T11:49:55.99",
            "user": {
                "name": "Test User 1",
                "userId": 1234
                },
            "ContactsEjected": 20
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post more details? What endpoints are you calling (and what parameters are you using)? What exactly is not working as expected? You're saying you used the attached code to fetch the data, but that does actually look like a response rather then a payload body

Comment: I used this request to fetch journey details

Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
GET /interaction/v1/interactions/unique-UUID-provided-by-SFMC/audit/all?versionNumber=2
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `JourneyID` in that particular route:

`https://{{tenant}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions/{{journeyId}}/audit/all`

You can get those with this route:

`https://{{tenant}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions`